# Is it possible to extend the data held on a user in Orchard Core?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcore

Using Orchard Core, is it possible to add fields to a User?

For example the company they're from, or some sort of preferences?

And then allow the user to change some of them, while keeping others read-only or hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to allow the end user to EDIT the fields yet, but I figured out how to add custom fields to the users...

Add a new content type and give it the stereotype "CustomUserSettings" - turn off all the Creatable, Listable, Draftable, Versionable, and Securable options too.

Then you can add all your fields to this content type and they will display in a tab on the user page (tab is titled what you named your content type) I named mine "User Settings"...